# groovy "BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy" JAVA SPRING BOOT 1.x -> 2.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, groovy

**UPDATE:**

I went through the groovy test cases and found the line of of code that causes this error. It's a Spring Boot Test Annotation:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyWebConfigClass.class)
```

I have a Java Spring Boot project (JDK 8) that was using 1.5.9 version and I just upgraded it to 2.4.4. I was using the `groovy-all` 2.4.12 jar and the spock-core. 1.2-groovy-2.4 version

Now, when I try to run `mvn install` or compile, I get this error:

```
 Error occurred while calling a method on a Groovy class from classpath.: InvocationTargetException: BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 
'url/path/here/to/groovy/unit/test/`  sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy -> [Help 1]
```

Has anyone seen there error before? I googled, but alot of questions were with Android and Groovy using Gradle, but this is a Java Spring project using Maven.

Comment: Please include the output of `mvn dependency:resolve` and the POM configuration for Groovy compilation. This smells like conflicting versions of Groovy (probably 2.4 and 2.5) are on the classpath.

Comment: I found the line of code doing it. Its in my groovy test cases, and its this annotation //@SpringBootTest(classes = MyWebConfigClass.class)

Comment: Please the effective versions of groovy and spock you are using or at least show how you override the versions in your project. The springboot bom brings in groovy 2.5 since sb 2.2 or 2.3 or even earlier.

Comment: hipe this will be helpful: https://dev.to/dineshbhagat/steps-to-upgrade-spring-boot-1-x-to-2-x-4196